# Get data for only Mondays in a large dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, datepart

How to get data for only Mondays from a dataset that has daily entries in SQL Server.

I tried this query but doesn’t give any result

```
select *
from table ame
where field-date > ‘07-31-2022’
and datepart(weekday, field-date) = ‘0’
```

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results. And hopefully your actual query isn't using those weird single quotes - because they aren't valid SQL. Also datepart returns an int, not a string, so you don't need quotes. For me Monday is weekday 2 - not 0, but it does depend on your settings.

Comment: The data set is a large database which has daily entries with multiple columns so difficult to show here. The single quotes are working in my query. I guess I was incorrectly putting 0 for Mondays (which I guess is in MySQL) but putting 2 without single quotes seems to be working. Running the query now! Thank you so much :)

Comment: "The data set is a large database" - thats why I said show sample data, a [mre] where you demonstrate the problem with the minimal amount of data and code. Those quotes aren't valid with SQL Server - are you sure you aren't using another RDBMS?

Comment: Of course you realise that performance could be terrible since you are using a function on your data and therefore making it unsargable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datename()` instead:

```
select *
from table ame
where field-date > ‘07-31-2022’
and datename(weekday, field-date) = 'Monday'
```

If you want to use `datepart()` then avoid single quote around integer value (in my regional setting value of Monday is 2):

```
select *
from table ame
where field-date > ‘07-31-2022’
and datepart(weekday, field-date) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The value for monday may differ for datepart(weekday) depending on your regional settings. One way to avoid problems with that is to query that value from a `know monday`, like 5 sep 2022 for example

Also note that I use an ISO format for the dates that works in any regional setting

```
select *
from   table ame
where  field-date > '20220731'
and    datepart(weekday, field-date) = datepart(weekday, '20220905')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
select count(*)
from payment
where extract(dow from payment_date ) = 1
```

It will count the data for Monday